# Which method is best to setup large React Project by create-react-app or web pack?

Tags: reactjs, setup-project

I am new to React i have some queries please answer me.

1. Which method is best to setup large React Project by create-react-app or web pack?
2. Which is the correct directory structure for large react project(type based or feature based)?

Comment: CRA and Webpack are not equivalent things. CRA just makes it a lot easier to get started, but still uses Webpack.

Comment: It's wrong to compare create-react-app and webpack. They are two separate things.

Comment: 1 - If you new to React, start with a small project. 2 - Directory structure is very subjective based on your opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you go with Webpack method because with that method you get better control over things + you will be knowing what all things are being used in your project + when you will be setting up everything from scratch it will be easy to debug things.Rest is your choice. but as you mentioned your project is very big I would suggest Webpack method.